# Playframework 2 - Add flash on a flashed mvc.Result

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

Is there a way to add new data in an already set flash scope without erasing the previous data set ?

```
Redirect(routes.Application.home).flashing("success" -> "OK").flashing("but" -> "BUT")
```

results the same as :

```
Redirect(routes.Application.home).flashing("but" -> "BUT")
```

I could do `flashing("success"->"OK", "but"->"BUT")` but I add the last flashed data in another object. Flashing data in a single call would require to rewrite a lot of things...

Comment: Can you not collect all the data in a Map and then set it in `.flashing` ?

Comment: Yes I could, but IMHO flashing should work as withHeaders withSession withXXX and used as a piling function

Comment: I ended up doing like this : Redirect(routes.Application.home).flashing("success" -> "OK", butComputation(param)). with à butComputation: Tuple2[String, String]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ccheneson adviced, I ended up collecting flashing elements in a `Map` then add this flash elements to the result using `Redirect(routes.Application.home).flashing(myFlashMap)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Action { request =>
  Redirect(routes.Application.home).flashing(request.flash + ("but"->"BUT"))
}
```

Comment: This would only pile a new flashed data to the flash of the last request. This in not what I want, I want to pile flash data in the current request.